# How to save time when user(for example) write in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am making a program for a baby and the logic of the program is like this:
What do you want to do?
1) Learn a word to Baby.
2)Show how many words Baby have learn.
3)Show the time when Baby has learn words.

If i click 3, then it will run like this:
Words that you have learn to me are:

```
Hey[4 April, 2018, 2:35PM]
Go[4 April, 2018, 2:35PM]
```

I tried with this(i don't really know what i did), but didn't work:

```
if action == "5"
time = Time.now
time.strftime("%d %B %Y %H")
puts "Words that i have learn till now(with time) are:" 
puts words + time
end
```

Words it's an array.

The code when baby learns word:

`if action == "1" && learnedwords.length <= 6 && learnedwords.scan(/\d+/).empty? && learnedwords.scan(/[!@#%^&*()_+{}[]:;'"\/\\?><.,]/).empty? 
fjalet.push(learnedwords)
puts "System:Word Fjala \"#{learnedwords}\" is now in baby's memory."` `

Comment: what contains the variable "fjalet"?

Comment: @Rohit Fjalet is an array.

Comment: Fjalet is in albanian, so in english mean words.

Comment: yeah, you should rename the variables to english, at least. Also elaborate on the question. Currently, it's very unclear.

Comment: Now i have translate the code, check it :)

Comment: Better, but still I have no idea what the question is about.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The program is about a Baby.

Comment: First Baby can't talk but i must learn words to Baby, and when i ask baby for example: Show me time that i have learn you the whole words.

Comment: It's a work for school, that's why i need help.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev

Comment: You should memorize the time at the moment baby _learns_ the word (the action that we don't see)

Comment: How do you save the words you have entered? You can probably save the corresponding time in a similar way.

Comment: Now it;s ok, better translate etc. Check it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev

Comment: BTW, Ruby does allow method and variable names to contain UTF-8 characters, so you could actually call your variable `fjalët`. But since Ruby's built-in methods have English names, this results in a weird language mix, e.g. `fjalët.each do`. Consider using English method and variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently save just the entered word via:

```
fjalet.push(learnedwords)
```

in order to also save the corresponding time, you could add word-time pairs to your array:

```
fjalet.push([learnedwords, Time.now])
```

and later on:

```
fjalet.each do |word, time|
  puts "#{word}[#{time.strftime('%-d %B, %Y, %-I:%M%p')}]"
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried with .each and it works(with the day only)
You saved me, thank you.